# How to fix: VB.NET text editor jump from one end of a construct (eg. IF or DO) to the other, no longer works

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Visual Studio Pro 2019 Version 16.11.1 shift-ctrl-up/down arrow used to jump to LOOP if cursor was at DO, or jump to END IF if was at IF, and vice versa.

But now it does nothing.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). This is a forum for asking questions. Your post seems doesn't contain a question, but rather seems more like a rant.

Comment: Does your `Ctrl` key still work to perform other operations, like `Ctrl+C` etc., and does it work outside of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the option "Highlight related keywords under cursor" enabled in Options.

Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Basic >> Advanced >>

[image]