# how to enable visual studio's text editor shift-ctrl-up/down arrow when not working work for BASIC

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Shift-ctrl-up/down is not jumping from one VB.NET construct (eg. IF or DO etc) to its end construct (eg. END IF or LOOP).

Used to work great.

I've been all over "Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Basic" but can't find what controls that.

VISUAL STUDIO 2019 PRO

Comment: Same Doug.  (I'm presently working through an account password problem with StackO on new laptop, and temporarily using Doug Ken there until fixed)

Comment: Now that you've upvoted, I have marked this as dupe. Did that answer work?

Comment: Thanks, djv.  My bad.   And that has the answer.  I will delete this one.

Comment: Mod closed my answer, so I guess you have no choice but to use the other question

Comment: [How to fix: VB.NET text editor jump from one end of a construct (eg. IF or DO) to the other, no longer works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012624/how-to-fix-vb-net-text-editor-jump-from-one-end-of-a-construct-eg-if-or-do-t)